# high order derivative of product

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, binomial-coefficients, arithmetic, binomial-theorem

Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, what is the form of
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)
$$
for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$?
I need to pull out $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)$ if possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Higher_derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Higher_derivatives). For this to be useful, you will need to find a formula for $d^n(x^{-1})/dx^n$, which you can do by inspection if you write out the first four or five cases.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it holds
$$
\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{n!}{j!}(-1)^{n-j}x^{j-n-1}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{j}f(x).
$$